# does not connect to some sites, when connected to vpn windvoss

Tags: vpn, pptp

using a Windows server, I created a pptp vpn connection, but when connecting, for example, to YouTube, it displays an error that the waiting time was exceeded, to create a vpnk connection, I used this guide https://www.snel.com/support/how-to-set-up-a-vpn-with-windows-server/

Comment: Are you sure you can access YouTube in the country that your VPN connects you to?

Comment: i used my server gateway which is in california

Comment: Your VPN connects you to a server in another geographic location. (I am assuming that here). Are you sure that you can access YouTube in that region/country?

Comment: yes , the server itself gets access to YouTube